# Surge in energy at start of N-body simulation

Tags: python, simulation, numerical-methods, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to use an n-body simulation to simulate the collapse of a globular cluster, starting from a point where the bodies all have 0 initial velocities generated in random positions of a sphere of a fixed radius and I am investigating the time taken to form an equilibrium system. However, when running my code when the particles initially come close together there is a large surge in potential energy. Is there a way to avoid this? I am using the leapfrog approximation to calculate subsequent velocities and positions of the particles.

[image]
[image]

initial conditions

```
sun_mass = 1.989e30


N = 50
mass = 25 * sun_mass
M = np.full([N],mass)    
R = 3.086e+16          # 1pc
epsilon = 0.1 * R
collision_radius = 7e8
V = np.zeros([N,3])
P = np.zeros([N,3])

t = 50000000 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
dt = 18000000 * 24 * 60 * 60



print(t/dt)

np.random.seed(54321)



for i in range(N):
    
    #M[i] = np.random.uniform(sun_mass, 100*sun_mass, 1)
    
    phi = np.random.uniform(0,(2*np.pi))
    costheta = np.random.uniform(-1,1)
    u = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    
    theta = np.arccos( costheta )
    r = R * (u) **(1/3)
    
    
    x = r * np.sin( theta) * np.cos( phi )
    y = r * np.sin( theta) * np.sin( phi )
    z = r * np.cos( theta )

    P[i] = (x,y,z)
```

code to run programme:

```
def programe(position, mass, velocity, softening, time, dt, R, collision_radius):
    
    #print(len(mass))
    no_of_time_steps = (round(time/dt))

    #all_positions = np.full((no_of_time_steps, len(mass), 3), 0.0)
    all_positions = []
    all_velocities = []
    #print(all_positions)
    #print(len(all_positions[0]))
    kinetic_energy = []
    potential_energy = []
    total_energy = []
    
    #previous_velocity = calc_previous_half_velocity(velocity, calc_acceleration(position, mass, softening), dt)
        
    for i in range(no_of_time_steps):
        
        position, mass, velocity = detect_collisions(position, mass, velocity, collision_radius)
        
        #all_positions[i] = position
        all_positions.append(position)
        all_velocities.append(velocity)
    
        'graph'
        plots = np.round(np.linspace(0,no_of_time_steps,num=500))
        for k in range(len(plots)):
            if i == plots[k]:
                print("test")
                #print(i)
                graph(position, mass, R, i, dt, k)
        
        'energies'
        kinetic_energy.append(calc_kinetic_energy(velocity, mass))
        potential_energy.append(calc_potential_energy(position, mass))
        total_energy.append(calc_total_energy(position, velocity, mass))
        
        'leap frog'
        velocity = calc_next_v_half(position, mass, velocity, softening, dt)    
        position = calc_next_position(position, mass, velocity, dt)    
        velocity = calc_next_v_half(position, mass, velocity, softening, dt)
        

    #columns_to_delete = len(all_velocities)
    #print(no_of_time_steps)
    #print(len(kinetic_energy), len(potential_energy), len(total_energy))
    
    
    all_positions = np.array(all_positions)
    all_velocities = np.array(all_velocities)
    #print(all_positions)
    graphing(all_positions, all_velocities, mass, time, dt, kinetic_energy, potential_energy, total_energy, no_of_time_steps, R)
    #print(len(mass))

    return(all_positions, all_velocities, kinetic_energy, potential_energy, total_energy)
```

leapfrog functions:

```
'LeapFrog functions'

'Acceleration Calculation'
def calc_acceleration(position, mass, softening):
    
    G = 6.67 * 10**(-11)
    
    N = position.shape[0] # N = number of rows in particle_positions array
    acceleration = np.zeros([N,3])
    
    #print(N)
    for i in range(N):
        #print(i)
        for j in range(N):
            if i != j:
                #print("j", j)
                dx = position[i,0] - position[j,0]
                dy = position[i,1] - position[j,1]
                dz = position[i,2] - position[j,2]
                
                #print(dx,dy,dz)
                
                inv_r3 = ((dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2 + softening**2)**(-1.5))
                
                acceleration[i,0] += - G * mass[j] * dx * inv_r3
                acceleration[i,1] += - G * mass[j] * dy * inv_r3
                acceleration[i,2] += - G * mass[j] * dz * inv_r3

    return(acceleration) #, print(acceleration))

def calc_previous_half_velocity(velocity, acceleration, dt):
    previous_velocity = np.zero_like(velocity)
    
    previous_velocity = velocity - acceleration * dt/2
    return(previous_velocity)

def calc_next_v_half(position, mass, velocity, softening, dt):
    half_velocity = np.zeros_like(velocity)
    half_velocity = velocity + calc_acceleration(position, mass, softening) * dt/2
    return(half_velocity)
    
def calc_next_velocity(position, mass, velocity, softening, dt):
    next_velocity = np.zeros_like(velocity)
    
    next_velocity = velocity + calc_acceleration(position, mass, softening) * dt
    
    return(next_velocity)


def calc_next_position(position, mass, velocity, dt):
    next_position = np.zeros_like(position)
    
    next_position = position + velocity * dt
    
    return(next_position)
```

other functions used:

```
def calc_CoM(position, mass):
        sumMR = np.zeros(3)
        sumM = 0.0
        position = np.array(position)
        for i in range(len(mass)):
            sumM += mass[i]
            sumMR += mass[i] * position[i]
        return(sumMR / sumM)


def calc_total_mass2(mass):
    total_mass = 0.0
    print((mass[0]))
    for i in range(len(mass)):
        total_mass += mass[i]
    return(total_mass)

def calc_total_mass(mass):
    total_mass = sum(mass)
    return(total_mass)

def calc_CoM_seperation(position, mass, i):
    new_mass = np.array(mass) 
    new_pos = np.array(position)
    new_mass[i] = 0.0
    new_pos[i] = 0.0
    position = np.array(position)
    r = np.linalg.norm(calc_CoM(new_pos, new_mass) - position[i])
    return(r)

def calc_seperation(p1, p2):
    return np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)
```

Comment: This is normal, the energy conversation property of Verlet and other symplectic schemes is only true if the system stays far enough away from singularities, here bodies falling into each other with a very close distance. As the system initially collapses into a sequence of multiple singular events, the energy may jump wildly, usually adding kinetic energy. You could add some rotation to the initial setup, that should avoid most of the close encounters. Or implement an elastic collision mechanism, this will also keep the system from getting too close to a singularity.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you also know if there is a way to stop the energy essentially almost exponentially trailing off other than using smaller timesteps?

Comment: Apart from the suggestions you got elsewhere of mollifying the potential to be finite, one could probably also treat close encounters as 2-body problems, where all other forces are small against the gravity of the two close bodies, and use the exact solution of that for the time-step. This would practically be an adapted variant of the more mechanical elastic collision. I do not know how that works in practice, this is just a plausible idea. But something like this in an advanced fashion is certainly used in long-term celestial simulations.